# How do I add Sepolia Testnet to Trust wallet

Tags: testnets, sepolia, trustwallet

I linked my Trust wallet to Chainlist to 'get access' to Sepolia Testnet. And I transferred some Sepolia ETH to the address, but it is yet to reflect in Trust, despite etherscan confirming this transaction for over an hour now. And the Sepolia docs don't state how to do this. Does this mean that Sepolia is not available on Trust?

Comment: The mobile application Trust Wallet didn't support test networks.